# Does My Nintendo have a point cap?

Tags: my-nintendo

I currently have 1440 Platinum Points and I'm wondering if there's a point cap in My Nintendo. When I had 830 Platinum Points, the Platinum Points Box appeared as full. When I claimed my 120 weekly Platinum Points the next week, thus adding up to 950 Platinum Points, the Platinum Points Box image didn't change. Even after I have added some points after that, it still didn't change.

[image: Platinum Coin Box]

**Is there a (known) point cap in My Nintendo, and what is it?**

Comment: How did you get 120 weekly? I'm only aware of 90 (for eShop, Miiverse, and My Nintendo sign-ins).

Comment: @JeremyAvalon You also get 30 points from visiting the http:/www.nintendo.com. All those points add up to 120 per week. Make sure you are logged in with your Nintendo account. As this is a hidden mission, make sure you check if you have gotten your points in your points history.

Comment: I was wondering why I had more platinum coins than I should have. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Currently have 1010 platinum points, so 1000 is not a limit for this one.

Answer (score 1):

The [three](https://www.reddit.com/r/MyNintendo/comments/4e7m9q/is_there_a_maximum_number_of_total_my_nintendo/) [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MyNintendo/comments/4d71ji/does_my_nintendo_have_a_limit_for_points/) [discussions](https://www.reddit.com/r/MyNintendo/comments/4drcwk/is_there_a_cap_on_the_number_of_platinum_andor/) I could find seem to imply that either there isn't a limit, or no one has publicly ran into the limit yet, and I couldn't easily find any other discussion or mention of it.